# shrink container to svg height

Tags: css, svg, webkit, height, containers

I have an assignment, where the user has to click in a fixed-aspect ratio image (compare clickable imagemap) that is embedded in an svg. Clicking the right area activates a link.
Somehow, I always get a 100% window height svg, hiding feedback text.

Displayed in Safari, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdbDs/) shows my problem; in Firefox things work as expected.
To the left you see the assignment ('some text' means 'click the circles') or an instructional image spanning more than the height of the svg on the right.

The scroll bar should not be visible and the feedback ('more text') should appear within the window, as there is plenty of space left:

```
.w50{width:50%}
.w30{width:30%}

<div class="w50">
    <image /> <!-- image height is 500 px -->
    <p> image with assignment</p>
</div>
<div class="w30 left">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0  341 455" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
    <image width="341" height="455" xlink:href="" />
    <a xlink:href="?cell1" id="a3776">
        <path d="m 127.72277,283.21783 a 9.9009905,11.386139 0 1 1 -19.80198,0 9.9009905,11.386139 0 1 1 19.80198,0 z" id="path2984" style="opacity:0.23275865;fill:#74d600;fill-opacity:0.22222224;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1" />
    </a><!-- etc -->
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="w30"> <!--height is 400 px -->
    <p>feedback text</p>
</div>
```